# Ошибка "message sent to deallocated instance" при переходе в альбомный режим на iPad

Tags: swift, ipad, ios8, orientation

При переходе в альбомный режим на iPad под iOS 8 возникает данная ошибка:

```
[MyViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fcd65376bf0
```

Answer (score 0):

Это сообщение не говорит о том, что существует проблема с «didSelectRowAtIndexPath:», в котором говорится, что существует проблема с вашим экземпляром «ModeViewController», который освобождается (больше не существует), когда метод «didSelectRowAtIndexPath:» Называемый.

Таким образом, проблема связана с временем жизни вашего экземпляра ModeViewController.